# Developing Photo Processing Functionality for Store

Tags: shopify

A client who has a Shopify website has asked me to develop functionality that will allow customers to upload images that can then be resized and cropped at the server level and placed into a PDF file for download.

We are planning on developing this functionality using a combination of PHP scripts and libraries:

GD or ImageMagick PHP extension 
tcpdf library for PDF generation

My question is whether something like this can be integrated directly into a Shopify website given that we’re developing in PHP, and if so, what's the best way to approach this integration?

They would like the image upload/cropping functionality to be a separate section of the site and it does not need to be integrated into the ui for viewing products – I’m hoping that this simplifies matters a bit.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything stopping you from being able to accomplish this.
You could build a Shopify app, which can be an [Application Proxy](http://www.shopify.com/technology/4627062-application-proxies-the-new-hotness) to look like seamless integration. It would handle the upload request of the image and the cropping/resizing.

You could handle where the data is stored, or use the [Asset API](http://api.shopify.com/asset.html).

There's a [shopify.php adapter](https://github.com/sandeepshetty/shopify.php) to interact with the API if needed, but unless I'm misunderstanding the requirements, it doesn't seem like there's a lot of integration that needs to read/write Shopify data. It seems like just the image uploading functionality needs to be presented to the user on the website.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices in terms of how you want to integrate this.

The easiest path is to embed an upload form (that points to your server) on the "thank you" page. You have access to the order number and some customer fields there so you can tie it to the uploaded image. Check out the Shopify FAQ page for example on how to do this: http://support.shopify.com/customer/portal/articles/236555-how-do-i-let-my-customers-upload-a-file-with-their-order-

Another approach would be to embed the form on the cart page. It is a little trickier to get the order number though. What you would need to do is [track the cart token](http://wiki.shopify.com/Tracking_Carts) by adding it as a hidden field in the form and capture it via [a order notification webhook](http://wiki.shopify.com/WebHooks). Thinking about it, you could probably track IP address as well.

Once you've figured out how to connect the order with the image, you can provide a convenient link in the Shopify Admin order page that would send them over to your site for cropping the image etc. This is configured on the App settings page.